# Short-circuit evaluation

Tags: lazy-evaluation, evaluation

I understand how the & and && operators differ in many languages. For example

```
if(condition1 && condition2)
```

will only evaluate condition2 if condition1 is true, and

```
if(condition1 & condition2)
```

will evaluate both condition1 and condition2 regardless of whether condition1 is true or not. My question is when you should use & over && (and respectively | and ||), since the result will always be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result will not always be the same. You may be thinking of `condition1` and `condition2` as fully-evaluated variables or constants, but they could be function calls with side effects, or `condition2` may be undefined if the value of `condition1` is one way or the other. (The canonical example for this is probably

```
if (x != null && x.isCondition()) { x.doSomething(); }
```

In my experience, I've almost never come across a case where I wanted the non-short-circuit evaluation, at least not in an `if` clause.

Answer (score 0):

& and | are bitwise operators which means they take the left and the right value and do a bit operation of AND or OR between them.

If you are doing a boolean logic then you want && and || in order to save some time.

You do not want to use & or | on boolean logic.

Likewise, if you are doing calculations on bits then using && and || does not make sense